# Airflow : Job <job-id> was killed before it finished (likely due to running out of memory)

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, airflow-2.x

I have a linear DAG with two tasks - first task's *truthy/falsy* value decide if second task would be executed. I am using ShortCircuitOperator for first task so that if needed second task can be bypassed. Following is my DAG code :-

```py
DAG_VERSION = "1.0.0"
with DAG(
    "sample_dag",
    catchup=False,
    tags=[DAG_VERSION],
    max_active_runs=1,
    schedule_interval=None,
    default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
) as dag:
    
    dag.doc_md = "Sample DAG"

    TASK_1 = ShortCircuitOperator(
        task_id="task_1",
        python_callable=test_script_1,
        executor_config=EXECUTOR_CONFIG,
    )
    
    TASK_2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="task_2",
        python_callable=test_script_2,
        executor_config=EXECUTOR_CONFIG,
    )

    TASK_1 >> TASK_2
```

However, when I try to run the DAG, then I get following in log for first task when it returns truthy value :-

**task_1 logs**

```
Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=sample_dag, task_id=task_1, execution_date=20220606T060000, start_date=20220606T070012, end_date=20220606T070014
[2022-06-06, 07:00:17 UTC] State of this instance has been externally set to success. Terminating instance.
[2022-06-06, 07:00:17 UTC] Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 18
[2022-06-06, 07:01:17 UTC] process psutil.Process(pid=18, name='airflow task runner: sample_dag task_1 scheduled__2022-06-06T06:00:00+00:00 7037', status='sleeping', started='07:00:12') did not respond to SIGTERM. Trying SIGKILL
[2022-06-06, 07:01:17 UTC] Process psutil.Process(pid=18, name='airflow task runner: sample_dag task_1 scheduled__2022-06-06T06:00:00+00:00 7037', status='terminated', exitcode=<Negsignal.SIGKILL: -9>, started='07:00:12') (18) terminated with exit code Negsignal.SIGKILL
[2022-06-06, 07:01:17 UTC] Job 7037 was killed before it finished (likely due to running out of memory)
```

I am using return value of first task in second task. When I try to log xcom value of first task inside second task then I get `None`, which cause second task to fail. This is my code for access xcom value for first task inside second task :-

```py
def test_script_2(**context: models.xcom) -> List[str]:
    task_instance = context["task_instance"]
    return_value = task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids="task_1")
    print("logging return value of first task ", return_value)
```

I am running Airflow 2.2.2 with kubernetes executor.

Is `None` xcom value due to out of memory issue in first task ? I tried by adding fixed value in first task, but again `None` was returned in second task with following log :-

**task_2 logs**

```
 Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=sample_dag, task_id=task_2, execution_date=20220606T095611, start_date=20220606T095637, end_date=20220606T095638
[2022-06-06, 09:56:42 UTC] State of this instance has been externally set to success. Terminating instance.
[2022-06-06, 09:56:42 UTC] Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 18
[2022-06-06, 09:57:42 UTC] process psutil.Process(pid=18, name='airflow task runner: sample_dag task_2 manual__2022-06-06T09:56:11.804005+00:00 7051', status='sleeping', started='09:56:37') did not respond to SIGTERM. Trying SIGKILL
[2022-06-06, 09:57:42 UTC] Process psutil.Process(pid=18, name='airflow task runner: sample_dag task_2 manual__2022-06-06T09:56:11.804005+00:00 7051', status='terminated', exitcode=<Negsignal.SIGKILL: -9>, started='09:56:37') (18) terminated with exit code Negsignal.SIGKILL
[2022-06-06, 09:57:42 UTC] Job 7051 was killed before it finished (likely due to running out of memory)
```

I am unable to find issue in the code. Would appreciate any hint on where I am going wrong and how to get xcom value of first task

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Im encountering this issue last couple days.

Comment: For me there was some issue with ShortCircuitOperator xcom value. So I explicitly specified xcom key for the ShortCircuitOperator task and retried in the next task. Also i sometimes get this in the log when the task completes and the pod is terminated